# How will the SameSite cookie extension changes in Chrome 80 affect Identity Server 4 users?

Tags: cookies, identityserver4

Barry Dorrans has nice [page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/) documenting the forthcoming changes by Chrome 80 (and others) to samesite cookie extensions and how it might affect OpenIdConnect auth flows in .net / .net core based web apps.
How will the SameSite cookie extension changes in Chrome 80 affect IdentityServer4 users?
What action (if any) do current identity server users need to take for this coming change to cookie behavior? Currently running IdentityServer4 2.13 with authcode and implicit flows.

Comment: Some reading https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get below console warring in Google Chrome and your Identity server failed to redirect to Client that could be React App or Angular App for Chrome version 80.

A cookie associated with a resource at was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

To Fix this , you need to do changes mention in below link -

https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/

NOTE : For .Net Core 2.2 , set SameSite = (SameSiteMode)(-1)
, For .Net Core 3.0 or above , set SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified

Also , for Chrome 80 version , add this extra condition -

```
 if ( userAgent.Contains("Chrome/8"))
            {
                return true;
            }
```