# AAD always failes with Corelation failed when samesite= strict or Lax

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, identity

Below is My Code Snippet which i am using

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureNonBreakingSameSiteCookies(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = (SameSiteMode.Lax);
            options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
              CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
            options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
               CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
        });

        return services;
    }

    private static void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
    {
        options.SameSite = (SameSiteMode.Lax);
        options.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Secure = true;
   }
```

Which always results into This is My Stack Trace

> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote
>   login. ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

Comment: Lax should be fine for top-level navigation. Are any frames involved here? Can you confirm that the correlation cookie in question is being set with the correct samesite property? Anything logged in your browser console? Are you using Chrome 80?

Comment: Yes I am using Chrome 80 when I set everything to none it works correctly just when I make it strict an lax it breaks i am using angular spa with silent refresh involved with it

Comment: That'll be why then - silent refresh involves an iframe and Lax cookies will be blocked when doing cross-site requests inside the iframe.

Comment: only option is to use to use None in this case then ??

Comment: Yes, although you're protected from malicious requests by the protocol in this case.

Comment: Just wanted to  add my flow here I Use Azure AD ==>> Hit the Login ==>> Goes to Login ask my Office 365 Details==>> Login SuccessFull from ==>> when returning to application it fails with above error

Comment: You could try to fix suggested on below link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868965/how-will-the-samesite-cookie-extension-changes-in-chrome-80-affect-identity-serv/61080926#61080926